# Using Git for Windows - Accidentally lost a ton of work. Can I get it back?

Tags: git, github, recovery

I am so confused and I think I've lost hours of work.

I was editing a file in Git earlier, and I saved it, but did not commit. I did do a few other file changes, and commited and pushed them. However, one file was messed up, so I clicked on the last successful commit, and pressed "roll back to this commit." To my horror, it erased all my uncommitted changes, and now I have no idea how to get them back since they were not committed.

Comment: If you committed or stashed it should be hanging out in the .git folder somewhere.  You can grep around to see which file it's in.

Comment: Before you do anything, make a (manual) copy of your git repository's directory to ensure that you don't overwrite any data that may still be left.

Comment: If something is not in the repository, and not in the stash, then this is rather a question of whether you are able to restore deleted file, not whether you are able to extract it from the repository. Git has nothing to do with it, unless you stashed the changes.

Comment: @Tadeck - the problem isn't that the file is deleted, but rather that it overwrote the file. I'm not sure how to recover that.

Comment: @user1465090: Check the log (`git log`): is there a commit you want to see back?

Comment: @user1465090: git never overrides the uncommitted changes, unless it's forced to do so. When you check-out the last successful commit, didn't it ask you to commit (or) stash the changes?

Answer (score 2):

You say that you didn't commit it. Unfortunately git only saves commits and not undone work. So, as sorry as I am, there is no way to use git to get your work back.

But you could try to [restore the deleted files](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20how%20to%20recover%20deleted%20data).

You might also want to have a look at [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/check-in-early-check-in-often.html) coding horror post.

Answer (score 1):

You could now (March 2013) check, with GitHub for Windows, if you can undo a "Rollback":

See "[Undo Button in GitHub for Windows](https://github.com/blog/1441-undo-button-in-github-for-windows)"

> we've added **Undo support for Discards, Commits, Rollbacks, and Merges**:

[image: Undo button]

I don't know if the rollback would save your *unstaged* and uncommitted changes though, so that new "Undo" button might not be a good enough solution.

Comment: "Discard all changes" just saved my project. All the files returned, which took a minute (I was attempting to re-do the first commits in smaller batches because the server was timing out due to the size of the first commit which failed...reverting the first commit was a bad idea)